# Creating thread in windows 8 with c language

Tags: c, windows-8, createthread

i wanted to know does the routine CreateThread works in windows 8 ?
if yes does it enough to add header file #include  or some other changes are added in windows 8

Comment: Unless you're specifically asking about Metro (or whatever they're called these days) apps, is there any reason to think it works differently from previous versions?

Comment: It should work in traditional desktop applications, nothing specific to Windows 8. Store applications use another way to implement multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

CreateThread function is supported by Windows Desktop Apps only but is not supported by Windows Metro-Style Apps. If you see the [Windows 8 architecture](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malaysia/archive/2012/02/13/windows-8-and-the-future-of-xaml-the-windows-runtime-winrt.aspx), you can find that Win32 library is not available for Metro Apps.
You will have to use [ThreadPool.RunAsync methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpool.runasync) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN page for CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't document any limitation for Windows 8 so it has to work. The "Requirements" section mentions that you should include a different

> Processthreadsapi.h on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012